# Склонение фамилий Цытович, Ероховец, Коврик

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Как изменять фамилии Цытович, Ероховец, Коврик?

Answer (score 1):

По мнению языковедов, предпочтение следует отдавать склонению без выпадения беглой гласной (Ероховец - Ероховеца). Вариант без выпадения гласной рекомендован для выводимости именительного падежа фамилии из её косвенных падежей.

Женские фамилии Цытович, Ероховец, Коврик не изменяются при склонении.

Answer (score 0):

По падежам: Цытовича, Ероховца, Коврика и т. д.